# rhe rails server does not work after changing gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

when i use `rails new (khar)` and go to khar dir run `rails server`
its very good and nice but when i change gem file to

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.1'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.7'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.40'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.2'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.6', '>= 2.6.3'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug', '~> 9.0', '>= 9.0.6'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'spring', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.14'
  gem 'mini_backtrace', '~> 0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.8', '>= 3.8.2'
end
```

rails server dose not work and give me this message

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile (LoadError)
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:13:in `block in silence_warnings'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:26:in `with_warnings'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:13:in `silence_warnings'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:53:in `initialize'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in `new'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in `initialize_i18n'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:15:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.2/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/professor/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/professor/Desktop/khar/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

where i do make a mistake?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the log file?

> Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile (LoadError)

Comment: im absolute beginner i read that but dont understand what it said

Answer (score 0):

Did you add more gems to Gemfile? You did not mention if you did. If so, did you run `bundle install` after adding gems?

Comment: after changing gem file i ran bundle install and after that this is happend